# Including links & images in $email_body with PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I have created an internal form that staff complete that should send an email to the user and then to the sales team.

I have posted a similar question but this is different as it specifically concerns adding links and images.

The form should send an email to both sales@ and the `$email` of the user/customer.

I have used this code for the form:

```html
<form method="post" name="process.php" action="process.php">
<p>Customer Name:</p><br><input type="text" name="name">
<p>Customer Email Address:</p><br><input type="text" name="email">
<p>Customer Order Number:</p><br><input type="text" name="order">
<p>Customer Order Date:</p><br><input type="text" name="date">
<p>Total Paid:</p><br><input type="text" name="cost">
<p>Tracking Number:</p><br><input type="text" name="tracking">
<br>
```

And have used this code for the `process.php` page.

```html
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$order = $_POST['order'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$cost = $_POST['cost'];
$tracking = $_POST['tracking'];

$email_from = "noreply@example.com";

$email_subject = "Your order details.";

$email_body = 
"Hello,\n $name.\n\n".
"Your order number is:\n $order".
"Your order was placed on:\n $date".
"Your total cost is:\n $cost".
"Your tracking number is:\n $tracking\n\n".
"You can track your order<a href=https://example.com/track>here</a>"
"Thanks,\n examplecompany \n";
<a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://example.com/assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="200px"> </a>

$to = $email;
$headers = "From: noreply@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: sales@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: contact@example.com \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

?>

 <p>Sending Email…</p>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10000;URL='https://staff.example.com/fulfilment/confirmorder/#useremail'"/>
```

I want this email to send to the user and BCC to the sales team. I also want the URL to be clickable and the image to show up when the email is sent. These can be done using the whole email as HTML but then the `$` PHP tags will not work.

Any suggestions to also send email to `sales@example.com`, include the link that can be clicked and the logo for the footer?

Comment: `"Thanks,\n examplecompany \n";
<a href="https://example.com"` this part should bring a error, you are mixing php code with html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the link inside `$email_body`. And since the email is HTML, you should use `<br>` for newlines, not `\n`.

For a long, multi-line string like this, a heredoc is useful.

```
$email_body = <<<EOM
Hello,<br> $name.<p>
Your order number is:<br> $order<br>
Your order was placed on:<br> $date<br>
Your total cost is:<br> $cost<br>
Your tracking number is:<br> $tracking<p>
You can track your order <a href="https://example.com/track">here</a>
Thanks,<br> examplecompany <br>
<a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://example.com/assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="200px"> </a>
EOM
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you. Just have the issue of it only sending to the user and not the sales email also.

Comment: Not sure why. From my research, adding the `Bcc:` line to `$headers` should do it.

Comment: No, that's not working either. Kind of strange to be honest.

Comment: Check the spam filter.

Comment: There's nothing there but I'm guessing that's the issue. I'll try on another domain